# HTTP POST for an idempotent action

Tags: api, http, rest

I'm designing a Web API to serve mobile applications and I have an action that checks if a given authorization key still is valid or not. In this request I send sensitive data (like the vendor_id of a specific device). I've also learned it's important to use POST method instead of GET in order to protect the information. However, the same action is idempotent because it just checks the validity. My question is: should I use POST or GET for this purpose?

Comment: `GET`, what perceived protection do you think you get from the `POST`?

Comment: POST does nothing to 'protect' the information.

Comment: How about the Apache logs? They store the URI query parameters, such as my sensitive data.

Comment: They don't if you don't want them to. And you could also include the POST data in them. The best option is to protect your logs.

Comment: I decided to follow the REST pattern (use GET for idempotent actions and POST for non-idempotent actions) and set the parameter on HTTP header of a GET request. Is it a bad idea?

Comment: @Orig DO you know "POST is NOT idempotent"  http://users.nccs.gov/~fwang2/web/jsp.html#idempotent_or_not

Answer (score -1):

i prefer to use POST even though this is a GET per the REST architecture; i would create a separate url: /object/get when i am using POST to do a GET-like operation to distinguish it from POST-like operations which would be POSTs to /object

Comment: How do you define "REST architecture"? Fielding doesn't say anything about using only GET for idempotent methods.

Comment: @TedBarth I did not use the word idempotent in my answer. The spirit of my answer is that if you want to fetch the representation of an object, rather than modify it, but you do not want to use HTTP GET because it is usually logged, then use a POST but do so at a separate URL than the object's URL.